# How can an element belong to an infinite number of events if these events don't necessarily overlap?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm struggling to understand the problem (b). I already solved (a).

[image]

How can it be possible that both of these are true:

1. "$\text{Let } A_1, A_2,... \text{ be events}$"
2. "$\omega \text{ belongs to an infinite number of events } A_1, A_2,...$"

The quote (1) declares just that there are events $A_1, A_2,...$.

If I understand it correctly, the quote (2) implies that there must be a number $k$ such that $\bigcap_{i=k}^{\infty}{A_i} \ne \emptyset$, because how would $\omega$ belong to an infinite number of events $A_k, A_{k+1},...$ if they have no common overlap between them? Yet this is never explicitly stated in the problem?

I'm a bit tired so I may be missing something obvious.

The problem is from "All of Statistics" by Wasserman, chapter 1 problem 3.

Comment: The idea here is that an outcome $\omega$ resides in $B_n$ provided it also resides in some $A_k$ where $k \geq n$. *If* $\omega$ is in an infinite number of $A_k$ then this is true for all $n$ (do you see why?), and then $\omega \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty B_n$. If $\omega$ is in only a finite number of $A_k$, then there is a maximum value $k_\text{max}$ for which this is true, and then $\omega \not\in B_n$ for any $n > k_\text{max}$ (strictly), and then it is not in the intersection of all $B_n$ either.

Comment: The answer to your direct question is that $\omega$ could belong to (say) all even $A_k$ and not to any odd $A_k$. Then the intersection of the $A_k$ could be $\varnothing$, but each $B_n$ would still contain $\omega$. You can be present in an infinite number of sets even if the intersection of all of the sets is the empty set.

Comment: Thanks, I think your last comment made it click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first claims from $(a)$ result from the properties of intersection and union, which I suppose you are familiar with. Otherwise you can try to prove it. The second claim $(b)$ is related to the definition of $\limsup$ of sequences of sets. More precisely, given a sequence of events $(A_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which belongs to $\Omega$ we define the $\limsup A_{n}$ as:
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_{n} = \bigcap_{n\geq 1}\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_{k}
\end{align*}

Alternatively, you can also prove (or consider) that such definition is equivalent to:
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_{n} = \{\omega\in\Omega : \limsup_{n\to\infty} 1_{A_{n}}(\omega) = 1\}
\end{align*}
where $1_{A_{n}}$ is the indicator function of the set $A_{n}$. From this definition it results that
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty}1_{A_{n}}(\omega) = 1 \Longleftrightarrow (\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |\sup_{k\geq n}1_{A_{k}}(\omega) - 1| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

Thus, if we choose $\varepsilon = 1$, we conclude that $\sup_{k\geq n}1_{A_{k}}(\omega) = 1$ for every $n\geq n_{1}$.

But what does it tell us? This exactly means that $\omega$ belongs to infinitely many sets just as you have claimed in the title of the question, otherwise we could conclude that $\sup_{n\geq k}1_{A_{k}}(\omega)$ should be zero from some point, which is clearly not the case.

Hopefully this helps!